# pgfplots - remove xz and yz background planes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I'm trying to get a 3dplot with only xy plane, without z axis and zx and zy planes.
To be clear, this is the best result i've got:

[image: plot from attached code]

and this is what i'd like to obtain:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title=Hello plot,
            hide z axis,
            grid=major,
            axis lines*=left,
            ]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            mesh/ordering=y varies,
            %mesh/rows=10,
            %mesh/cols=53,
            %scatter,
            ] table {
week    year    pax
0       2017    0
0       2018    77

1       2017    89
1       2018    0

2       2017    49
2       2018    25

3       2017    76
3       2018    53

4       2017    20
4       2018    46

5       2017    47
5       2018    35

6       2017    28
6       2018    74

7       2017    123
7       2018    116

8       2017    70
8       2018    14

9       2017    78
9       2018    74

10      2017    205
10      2018    64 
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Suggestion?

Comment: Welcome! You could just draw the lines by hand. Please add the preamble to your code.

Comment: `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,4,...,8}
  {\draw[thin,gray] (#1,2017)--(#1,2018);} 
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2017.5,2018}
  {\draw[thin,gray] (0,#1)--(10,#1);} 
`

Comment: @marmot thanks for your reply! I've not added preamble, because it's just a _\usepackage{pgfplots}_, nothing strange
What you mean with draw the lines by hand? I'd like to _remove_ them... And to be more specific: the main problem it's the vertical space, not removed when i remove the z axis

Answer (score 2):

What I meant is this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            title=Hello plot,
            hide z axis,
            %grid=major,
            axis lines*=left,
            ]
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2,4,...,8}
        {\draw[thin,gray] (#1,2017)--(#1,2018);}    
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{2017.5,2018}
        {\draw[thin,gray] (0,#1)--(10,#1);} 
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            mesh/ordering=y varies,
            %mesh/rows=10,
            %mesh/cols=53,
            %scatter,
            ] table {
week    year    pax
0       2017    0
0       2018    77

1       2017    89
1       2018    0

2       2017    49
2       2018    25

3       2017    76
3       2018    53

4       2017    20
4       2018    46

5       2017    47
5       2018    35

6       2017    28
6       2018    74

7       2017    123
7       2018    116

8       2017    70
8       2018    14

9       2017    78
9       2018    74

10      2017    205
10      2018    64 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, maybe a viable workaround. But there's still too much vertical space (the z axis is simply non shown, but the space is here).